# dell 5420 and ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04

I use a dual system (windows and Ubuntu 18.04) on a DELL 5620 i7-1165G7 laptop
And some things don't work:
The computer does not share a screen for an external monitor.
No F6 and F7 function (screen brightness)
And scroll on touchpad.
This is what has been found so far and all function do work on windows.
Suggestions?

Comment: You weren't specific as to what software stack you're talking about.  Ubuntu 18.04 Desktop, 18.04 Server, what ISO did you use to install (ie. are you using an older GA stack thus 4.15 kernel?, or a newer HWE stack thus 5.4 kernel? which is chosen at install time by the ISO used to install if desktop). I'd for sure suggest HWE kernel stack if you're using the GA stack.

Comment: kernel v 5.4.0-73-generic
I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 Desktop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The machine you are using is *far* too new for the kernel in Ubuntu 18.04. If you would like to make proper use of your graphics card (not to mention all the CPU power you're leaving on the table), you will need to upgrade to 20.04 or 21.04. The machine [has been certified for 20.04](https://certification.ubuntu.com/hardware/202010-28335), which means you can make use of [the hardware enablement stack](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack).

If you absolutely must use 18.04 for specific applications, consider using those tools in a Docker container or a virtual machine.